# Secure string read as string

Tags: json, powershell

I have a data structure that's been imported from a saved JSON file. One of the elements written out is actually a secure string, not a standard string. When read back in with `ConvertFrom-Json` it shows as a standard string. I can't use it to build a credential as a result.

How do I tell powershell that this data is actually a securestring, without trying to encode it?

Comment: JSON doesn't support securedstring types, I guess you want to convert an encrypted string to a securedstring using [ConvertTo-SecuredString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the string through [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-6):

```
$secureString = 'ENCRYPTED_STRING' | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

If your original `SecureString` was created with a specific key, you'll have to provide the `-Key` or `-SecureKey` argument in order to construct the `SecureString` object.

Comment: Thanks Bender. That different key was the problem.